# JAVA: Signal start of new input with space instead of enter

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I have an assignment to create a program that will take input and print it to the console. Pretty simple. There is one issue though. I have to store the information in separate variables but the input looks like this.

```
Input:
Blah 123 Green
```

I'm aware that I can create a single scanner input tied to a single variable that will store all of that as one String but for the assignment Blah, 123, and Green would all have to be stored in different variables. Normally what I would do if I could use the enter key to signal new input would be

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String first = scan.nextLine();
int second = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
String third = scan.nextLine();
```

but in this case, the spaces have to act as the enter key instead. how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `next()` to read individual inputs:

```java
String first = scan.next();
int second = scan.nextInt());
String third = scan.next();
```